# Javascript Filter integers

Tags: javascript, parseint

I'm learning javascript on FreecodeCamp. And, the solution of my problem doesn't help me more.
We have to filter integers in an array which is saved in const variable.

```
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2];
const squareList = (arr) => {
  "use strict";
const squaredIntegers = arr.filter( (num) => num > 0 && num % parseInt(num) === 0 ).map( (num) => Math.pow(num, 2) );
 return squaredIntegers;
};

const squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);
console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

and I cannot understand really this part `num % parseInt(num) === 0 ).map( (num) => Math.pow(num, 2) );`

Why using parseint() method and Math.pow. Someone could explain me why?

thanks.

Comment: The first one is basically an integer check. If `num` is an integer, `num` and `parseInt(num)` are equal, and thus `num % num === 0` The second squares `num`. A better way is to use `num => num * num` here btw.

Comment: There are two methods used here. First one is `filter( (num) => num > 0 && num % parseInt(num) === 0 )`. It filters an array and returns an array with numbers greater that 0. Second one `map( (num) => Math.pow(num, 2) )` gets a returned array after first one, and returns an array with each element of previous array but squared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`parseInt(num)` gives an integer part of num, for example, `parseInt(3.14) === 3 //true`.
Using `num % parseInt(num)` basically gives a difference between the number and its integer part. If it isn't `0`, the number is thrown out.
`Math.pow(num)` gives a squared number, which is returned to the new array. Though, `num * num` is faster in that regard, not having to include a module and to call an object property.

Other than that, the code is very crammed in the solution, and I would suggest to break it down to improve readability. Seems like the style in which it is written adds to the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

```
const squaredIntegers = arr.filter( (num) => num > 0 && num % parseInt(num) === 0 ).map( (num) => Math.pow(num, 2) );
 return squaredIntegers;
```

Here inside the `filter`, it is checked if `num` is positive `(num>0)` and `num` is an `integer`. For checking for integer. `num % parseInt(num)` parseInt changes the num to an `integer`, and the `modulus` of a number with itself is 0 so the condition `num % parseInt(num)==0`. `Math.pow(num,2)` is used to square the num.

Answer (score 1):

```
const squaredIntegers = arr.filter(
    (num) => {
        if (Number.isInteger(num) && num >0){
        return num;
}}
).map((num) => num *num); // Math.pow(num, 2) can also be used here
return squaredIntegers;
};
```

This could be an easier solution for your problem, although all the above solutions work fine as well. `num*num` could also be replaced with  `Math.pow(num, 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try This One it will not only filter out the negative once also returns only those which are Integer.

```
const squareList = arr => {
  let myArr = arr
        .filter(item => item > 0)
        .reduce((a, current) => a.concat(current*current) , [])
        .filter(num => Number.isInteger(num));
  return myArr;
};

const squaredIntegers = squareList([4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2]);
console.log(squaredIntegers);// Prints : [16, 1764, 36] on console.
```

Answer (score 0):

Many people have explained this in a very good way. You can also do this part

```
const squaredIntegers = arr.filter( (num) => num > 0 && num % parseInt(num) === 0 ).map( (num) => Math.pow(num, 2) );
```

Like this, and it should work without problems. Hopefully, this helps.

```
const squaredIntegers = arr.filter( (num) => num > 0 && num % 1 === 0 ).map( (num) => num * num );
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to use the reduce statement is this

```
const squareList = arr => {
  // Only change code below this line
  let myArr = arr.filter(user => Number.isInteger(user) && user > 0)
               .reduce((sqr,num) => sqr.concat(num*num), []);
  return myArr;
  // Only change code above this line
};

const squaredIntegers = squareList([-3, 4.8, 5, 3, -3.2]);
console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

where Number.isInteger() is used to filter off decimals and user > 0 is used to filter off negative values from the arr

Answer (score 0):

Here's a much easier way to fix your problem :

```
  const squareList = arr => {
  let squaredNumbers = arr
  .filter(elem => elem > 0 && Number.isInteger(elem))
  .map(elem => elem * elem)
  return squaredNumbers;
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).